# Plotting results of several Bland-Altman analysis

Tags: r, graph, boxplot

I compared several diagnostic methods to a gold standard using Bland-Altman plots. Now I would graphically represent the difference in agreement between each method and the gold standard in one single plot. I'm trying to plot means, confidence intervals and variance derived from the various Bland-Altman plots as horizontal boxplots, but I don't know I to do that.
I have a dataframe like this:

```
Method    LCL    mean    UCL    var
A         -5     4       15     27
B         -9     2       13     33
C         -8     4       16     36
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Corrado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to realize that a "true" boxplot is a specific type of plot based on non-parametric statistics, none of which you have offered. If you want to call it something else you are free to do so and you can use the `bxp` function to do the plotting. You need to create a matrix with 5 rows and 3 columns with the values for whisker and box parameters. You may be thinking that the variance could be used to construct standard deviation?

```
 dat <- read.table(text="Method    LCL    mean    UCL    var
 A         -5     4       15     27
 B         -9     2       13     33
 C         -8     4       16     36
 ", header=TRUE)
 dat$sdpd <- dat$mean + dat$var^0.5
 dat$sdmd <- dat$mean - dat$var^0.5
 dat
#------
  Method LCL mean UCL var      sdpd      sdmd
1      A  -5    4  15  27  9.196152 -1.196152
2      B  -9    2  13  33  7.744563 -3.744563
3      C  -8    4  16  36 10.000000 -2.000000
#----------
 bxpm <- with(dat, t(matrix(c(LCL, sdmd, mean, sdpd, UCL), 3,5)))
 bxpm
#----------
          [,1]      [,2] [,3]
[1,] -5.000000 -9.000000   -8
[2,] -1.196152 -3.744563   -2
[3,]  4.000000  2.000000    4
[4,]  9.196152  7.744563   10
[5,] 15.000000 13.000000   16

 bxp(list(stats=bxpm, names=dat$Method ), main="Not a real boxplot\n
                                                Perhaps a double dynamite plot?")
```

Comment: You're right, I didn't mean to create a "true" boxplot, but rather something graphically looking like a boxplot. Your solution worked perfectly, thank you!

Comment: I always found it sad to see accepted response without any upvote. (+1)

Answer (score 1):

I can't provide you with working R code as you didn't supply raw data (which are needed for boxplots), and it is not clear what you want to display as nothing indicates where your gold standard comes into play in the given aggregated data (are these repeated measurements with different instruments?), unless the reported means stand for difference between the ith method and the reference method (in which case I don't see how you could use a boxplot). A basic plot of your data might look like

```
dfrm <- data.frame(method=LETTERS[1:3], lcl=c(-5,-9,-8), 
                   mean=c(4,2,4), ucl=c(15,13,16), var=c(27,33,36))
# I use stripchart to avoid axis relabeling and casting of factor to numeric
# with default plot function
stripchart(mean ~ seq(1,3), data=dfrm, vertical=TRUE, ylim=c(-10,20),
           group.names=levels(dfrm$method), pch=19)
with(dfrm, arrows(1:3, mean-lcl, 1:3, mean+lcl, angle=90, code=3, length=.1))
abline(h=0, lty=2)
```

However, I can recommend you to take a look at the [MethComp](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MethComp/index.html) package which will specifically help you in comparing several methods to a gold standard, with or without replicates, as well as in displaying results. The companion textbook is

> Carstensen, B. [*Comparing Clinical Measurement Methods*](http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0470694238.html). John Wiley
>   & Sons Ltd 2010

[image]

Comment: Thank you, the MethComp package seems to be exactly what I need! However, I didn't understand how it plots comparison among several methods, I have to study it with attention. Thanks!

Comment: For multiple methods, Carstensen suggests to display a scatterplot matrix of BA plots (in your case, pairwise differences between your three methods and your reference). Check one of his course here: [Statistical Analysis of Method Comparison Studies](http://192.38.117.59/~bxc/MethComp/Courses/).

Comment: And I hope to reduce sadness stemming from good advice without appropriate recognition as well.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using R's [boxplot()](http://www.statmethods.net/graphs/boxplot.html) command?

I think by default it assumes you are supplying the raw data, and specifying a factor with which to segment the data. It will compute it's own bounds for the box, which may or may not correspond to what you are using. If you want to be able to easily fine tune r-graphics, and you have a little bit of time to learn, checkout hadly wikham's ggplot2. It's powerful, flexible, and pretty!

Good luck!.